# How to solve internal error: retry receiver class not set yet and GCMBaseIntentService : SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting this logcat on running my app on Micromax Canvas 2, my phone is configured to Google services and google account, Here I am **not getting the GCM registration ID** whereas I am **getting it in emulator**. Any suggestions why ? Thanx in advance.

```
07-11 13:52:48.145: V/InputMethodManager(16539): focusOut: android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView{41990460 VFED..CL .F....ID 0,53-480,113 #7f070024 app:id/txt_sitename} 

mServedView=android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView{41990460 VFED..CL .F....ID 0,53-480,113 #7f070024 app:id/txt_sitename} winFocus=false
07-11 13:54:05.461: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(16539): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
07-11 13:54:05.461: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(16539): GCM IntentService class: dotsandcoms.android.siteuplitenew.GCMIntentService
07-11 13:54:05.463: V/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Acquiring wakelock
07-11 13:54:05.469: V/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-677416186780-1
07-11 13:54:05.470: D/dalvikvm(16539): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-11 13:54:05.470: D/dalvikvm(16539): create new thread
07-11 13:54:05.470: D/dalvikvm(16539): new thread created
07-11 13:54:05.470: D/dalvikvm(16539): update thread list
07-11 13:54:05.471: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: interp stack at 0x5e527000
07-11 13:54:05.471: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: created from interp
07-11 13:54:05.471: D/dalvikvm(16539): start new thread
07-11 13:54:05.471: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: notify debugger
07-11 13:54:05.471: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13 (IntentService[GCMIntentService-677416186780-1]): calling run()
07-11 13:54:05.476: E/GCMRegistrar(16539): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
07-11 13:54:05.476: V/GCMRegistrar(16539): Registering receiver
07-11 13:54:05.477: D/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null
07-11 13:54:05.477: D/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
07-11 13:54:05.477: D/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Scheduling registration retry, backoff = 3515 (3000)
07-11 13:54:05.490: V/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Releasing wakelock
07-11 13:54:05.497: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: exiting
07-11 13:54:05.497: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: bye!
07-11 13:54:08.995: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(16539): onReceive: com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY
07-11 13:54:08.995: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(16539): GCM IntentService class: dotsandcoms.android.siteuplitenew.GCMIntentService
07-11 13:54:08.995: V/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Acquiring wakelock
07-11 13:54:09.001: V/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-677416186780-2
07-11 13:54:09.003: D/dalvikvm(16539): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-11 13:54:09.004: D/dalvikvm(16539): create new thread
07-11 13:54:09.004: D/dalvikvm(16539): new thread created
07-11 13:54:09.004: D/dalvikvm(16539): update thread list
07-11 13:54:09.004: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: interp stack at 0x5e527000
07-11 13:54:09.004: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: created from interp
07-11 13:54:09.004: D/dalvikvm(16539): start new thread
07-11 13:54:09.004: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: notify debugger
07-11 13:54:09.004: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13 (IntentService[GCMIntentService-677416186780-2]): calling run()
07-11 13:54:09.010: V/GCMRegistrar(16539): Registering app dotsandcoms.android.siteuplitenew of senders 677416186780
07-11 13:54:09.018: V/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Releasing wakelock
07-11 13:54:09.022: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: exiting
07-11 13:54:09.022: D/dalvikvm(16539): threadid=13: bye!
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug,

*If you get the error "internal error: retry receiver class not set yet," then you've got an older version of the client gcm.jar. This is the patch that fixes the error.
Instead of patching your local version of GCMBroadcastReceiver.java in the Android SDK, you can download either the source or the updated gcm.jar file from the GCM repository.*

[Link to Patch](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/diff?spec=svne1a099b36566c265f758facf70b8f4f3684ed0ea&r=e1a099b36566c265f758facf70b8f4f3684ed0ea&format=side&path=/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBroadcastReceiver.java)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/?name=#git%2Fgcm-client-deprecated%2Fdist this gcm.jar should I take ?

Comment: Correct, thats the newest one

Comment: I have put it in the libs folder where the old one was previously but then now there errors in my whole project wherever I am using GCM for eg could not resolve com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService; and com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

Comment: Under project properties, add the lib again

Comment: no effect what so ever.. project is not accepting the new jar. As soon as I put the old one all errors go.

Comment: ok what about GCMBaseIntentService : SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, this error...have any idea ???

Comment: @Sydroid Did you add `gcm.jar` to your Java Build Path? And did you check the `Android Private Libraries` check box in the `Order and Export` tab?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have 2 project, in first proyect not work, in the second yes ... I don't understand, not is problem of "jar"